# Generating unique random number lists

Tags: random

I am new in programming. I have an array containing, let's say 20 elements and first I want to randomly select two elements from it and record them. Then I will select two elements from the array of twenty elements again and record them. The process continues, let's say 10 times and in these 10 draws, I do not want to repeat any of the two elements that I have already drawn.

I used `RandomSample` to generate random numbers.

```
j = 0;
For[i = 0, i < 2, i++,
  Yarray[j] = RandomSample[Range[8], 2];
  Print[Yarray[j]];
  j++;]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site Daniel.  That's a good question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways:

- Use `RandomSample` to generate a random list with twice the sample size you need and partition:

Example: Draw 5 random pairs from `Range[20]`:

```
 Partition[RandomSample[Range[20], 10], 2]
 (*  result:  {{20, 14}, {19, 8}, {5, 1}, {12, 15}, {17, 2}} *)
```

- `Nest` a composite function that draws one pair and deletes it from the base list sequentially:

Example: Draw 5 random pairs from the list of letters `{a,...,z}`:

```
samples = {}; 
Nest[( samples = Append[samples, RandomSample[#, 2]]; 
      Complement[#, Flatten@samples]) &,  CharacterRange["a", "z"], 5]; 
samples
(* result: {{"m", "c"}, {"g", "h"}, {"r", "l"}, {"n", "x"}, {"u", "a"}} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Given

```
elements = Table[Unique["el"], {20}]
```

> {el3, el4, el5, el6, el7, el8, el9, el10, el11, el12, el13, el14, \
>   el15, el16, el17, el18, el19, el20, el21, el22}

What you want is equivalent to

```
Partition[RandomSample[elements], 2]

{{el22, el17}, {el12, el6}, {el5, el19}, {el7, el18}, {el9, 
  el4}, {el13, el21}, {el11, el3}, {el10, el16}, {el14, el15}, {el8, 
  el20}}
```

If you want less sets (say 3), you can always do

```
Partition[RandomSample[elements], 2]~Take~3
```

> {{el4, el18}, {el10, el8}, {el19, el21}}

or more efficiently

```
Partition[RandomSample[elements, 2 3], 2]
```

However, if we want to implement your algorithm as you described it (3 times in this example)

```
Reap[Nest[Complement[#, Sow@RandomSample[#, 2]] &, elements, 3]][[2, 1]]
```

I'll break this down. `Complement[#, Sow@RandomSample[#, 2]] &`. This is a function that takes one argument. The argument should be a list with the remaining elements. It takes 2 random elements of those (`RandomSample[#, 2]`) and `Sow`s them (puts them aside for later recollection). Then, it returns the original list without those 2 elements.

We apply that function to the whole list of elements, 3 times (`Nest[function, elements, 3]`)

Finally, we collect the stuff we put aside in the process (`Reap[...][[2, 1]]`)

Answer (score 6):

Here is one possible solution:

```
SetAttributes[draw, HoldFirst]

draw[var_, n_] /; n <= Length@var :=
  # &[Take[var, n], var = Drop[var, n]]
```

Initialize the set:

```
set = RandomSample@Range@20;
```

Draw your elements.  I use `Table` rather than the `For` loop.

```
Table[
 draw[set, 2],
 {10}
]
```

Output:

> ```
> {{7, 16}, {2, 11}, {17, 14}, {9, 12}, {10, 3},
>  {15, 13}, {19, 1}, {20, 6}, {8,4}, {18, 5}}
> ```

Confirm that `set` is now empty:

```
set
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

---

So how does this work?  Let me break it down.  The set of shuffled numbers is stored as an assignment to a Symbol named `set`.  To handle this Symbol itself my function needs a `Hold*` attribute.  I choose `HoldFirst`:

```
SetAttributes[draw, HoldFirst]
```

I then define a function using pattern matching that takes two parameters: `var` and `n`, and I include a check on these elements with `Condition` (`/;`).  I want my function to do two things:

1. take the first two elements from the `set` given as `var`. This is done with `Take[var, n]`
2. remove these from `set` itself.  This can be done with `var = Drop[var, n]`

Since I want to return the result of the first operation, but it must be performed before the second, I use a "pure function" (using `Function` and `Slot`):  `# &` which simply returns (only) the first argument it is given, and then give each of the operations above as arguments:

```
draw[var_, n_] /; n <= Length@var :=
  # &[Take[var, n], var = Drop[var, n]]
```

Comment: +1 for the pass-by-reference method!

Comment: @István Thanks.  I decided that taking the OP's question literally made for a much more interesting answer.